# How to compute the Gini index, the entropy and the classification error from a decision tree?

Tags: classification, decision-trees, cross-entropy, gini-index

How to find the **Gini index, the entropy, and the classification error** for **each node** of the tree in the figure below.
[image]

Please help me to compute them.

Comment: We have to assume that A and B are intermediary steps, being the squares the end nodes, isn't it? I ask it because apparently that's note the code usually followed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree check **Overview** section.

Answer (score 1):

The higher the Gini index better it is, in this case, there are two ways to split the data, 1st way is by color, 2nd way is by shape. The Weighted Gini index will decide which attribute should be used for splitting.
Gini index tries to put all the similar things into one bucket.